# How can I use ffmpeg to change 360 video projection?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, projection, 360-virtual-reality

I want to convert 360 videos from equirectangular to cubic projection. How can I do this with ffmpeg? What are other efficient open source approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use native FFmpeg v360 filter, it supports more features that any other solution.

Comment: answer without explanation is not an answer, is just an invitation to do by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You need the [v360](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360) filter (make sure you use the latest ffmpeg build as older versions don't include it).

For instance:

```
-vf v360=equirect:c3x2
```

3x2/6x1/1x6 cubemap layouts are available.

Answer (score 4):

You can try out by compiling with the transform filter, developed by Facebook

[**Transform**](https://github.com/facebook/transform)

> Transform is a video filter that transforms 360 video in
> equirectangular projection into a cubemap projection

**Build Instructions**:

> Transform is implemented as an ffmpeg video filter. To build
> Transform, follow these steps:
>
> Checkout the source for ffmpeg
>
> Copy vf_transform.c to the libavfilter subdirectory in ffmpeg source
>
> Edit libavfilter/allfilters.c and register the filter by adding the line: REGISTER_FILTER(TRANSFORM, transform, vf); in the video
> filter registration section
>
> Edit libavfilter/Makefile and add the filter to adding the line: OBJS-$(CONFIG_TRANSFORM_FILTER) += vf_transform.o in the filter
> section
>
> Configure and build ffmpeg as usual

Comment: Works very well, thanks for pointing out this recent ressource. I haven't found yet how to make it work with OSX brew workflow but it's super easy to get running on Linux